# MYSQL not connecting to LARAVEL but credentials are correct and cant use artisan command

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

On the webpage this is produced:
`sqlstate[hy000] [1698] access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (sql: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = categories and table_type = 'base table')`

Attempts:

1. `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear` => Not working since artisan displays the mysql error; so artisan is useless, it must be a database issue
2. env file credentials are correct
3. `sudo systemctl restart mysql.service` => problem persists
4. restart the DO Server with `sudo poweroff` => problem persists

Answer (score 0):

The Solution:

1. `sudo mysql -u root -p` => login to mysql as root with password
2. `use mysql;` => use the mysql database
3. `UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE USER='root';` => change the authentication type of root to mysql_native_password
4. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` => reload the grant table
5. `service mysql restart` => restart mysql

After this is completed, the error should be cleared.